# How to add security to run Ignite Web Console in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

I am running Ignite Web Console and Web Agent in k8s v1.9, but connection fails when using security - works fine without security. I am able to access Ignite REST API by passing 'X-Signature' value in Header using Postman, but see no way to do this through the Web Console. Same with dBeaver.

Answer (score 1):

Web Console do not support connection to secured cluster.

I created issue: [IGNITE-8428](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-8428) Web Console: Support connect to secured cluster.

You can track it.